# Edit row in bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have used `boostrap-table` in my JSP page

```
<table id="mytable" 
   data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-hover" id="table-pagination " 
   data-url="lots.json" 
   data-toggle="table"
   data-pagination="true"
   data-show-pagination-switch="true"
   data-sort-order="desc" 
   data-search="true"
   data-show-refresh="true" 
   data-show-columns="true"

   data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"                     
>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="machine" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">machine</th>
            <th data-field="mould" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">mould</th>
            <th data-field="lot" data-editable="true" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">LOT</th>         

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and I have inserted the [editable method](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#extensions/editable.html) in my 3rd column which in front-end it works.

I try to catch the new value I insert in my table(e.g I edit a row and I insert the '12'): I have tried this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable').on('editable-save.bs.table', function(field, row, oldValue, $el){
        console.log("1 "+ field);
        console.log("2 "+ row);
        console.log("3 "+ oldValue);
        console.log("4 "+ $el);
    });    
});
```

but in console i get:

```
1 [object Object]
2 lot
3 [object Object]
4 002400000 // this is the old one
```

Comment: Here is the ediatble extension optins, I think. Here you should find an option, what happens, when you finished the edit, and in that callback you need to call an ajax request to a script on server side: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable

Comment: This will be that method: `onEditableSave(editable-save.bs.table)` from here: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/editable

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable').on('editable-save.bs.table', function(e, field, row, oldValue){
        console.log("1 "+ field);
        console.log("2 "+ row[field]);
        console.log("3 "+ row.lot);
        console.log("4 "+ oldValue);
    });    
});
```

Here you can get new value using row[field] or row.lot